# Error URL pdfMake.js with Ionic Cordova App

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, pdfmake

I have a problem using pdfMake.js library. This library is supposed to generate PDF, client-side only.
It works well with chrome, Firefox... 
But when I launch my ionic app on a device (Android in my case), I have the following error :

```
 CordovaWebViewImpl﹕ Blocked (possibly sub-frame) navigation to non-allowed URL: data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJf39/f0KNiAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvRXh0R1.......
```

I encountered this problem before with AngularJs for example for Blobs...and using the following configuration worked :

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension|blob):/);
```

BUT not here... :(

Do you have any idea how to allow the data/pdf ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to add permissions to your App inside manifest.xml file

Comment: Do you know which one please ?

Comment: have you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />